# Session is destroyed when browser is closed. | ZF2

Tags: php, session, cookies, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to implement session and cookies in my zend application. Session is working fine within the tabs but when I reopen the browser then sessionId in the cookie changes and my application shows user is not logged in.

Below is the code of Module.php of Application Module.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration' ));

        $this->initSession(array(
            'remember_me_seconds' => 864000,                  
            'use_cookies' => true,
            'cookie_httponly' => true,  
            'cookie_secure' => false,       
        ));
    } 

public function initSession($config){
        $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
        $sessionConfig->setOptions($config);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
        $sessionManager->start();
        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);

    }

public function loadConfiguration(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $session = new Container('user_session_data');

        if(isset($session->user_id)){
            //user is logged in set his data to viewModel
            $controller->layout()->user_id = $session->user_id;
            $controller->layout()->firstName = $session->firstName;
            $controller->layout()->lastName = $session->lastName;
            $controller->layout()->profilePicture = $session->profilePicture;
        }
    }
```

I access these values in my layout.phtml file. Below is the code to save session data when user is successfully logged in.

```
$session = new Container('user_session_data');
            if($session->user_id){
                echo "You are already logged in";
            }
            // store user details in session
            $session->user_id = $responseDataArray['data']['id'];
            $session->firstName = $responseDataArray['data']['firstName'];
            $session->lastName = $responseDataArray['data']['lastName'];
            $session->profilePicture = $responseDataArray['data' ['profilePicture'];
```

I don't know what I am missing to persist session data.

Comment: Why didn't you use default Zend/Auth ? ...
This problems are already solved there, read the link:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html

Authentication is simple in ZF2, just write your own AuthAdapter and do
 `
$adapter = new YourNewAdapater($username,$password);
$auth = new AuthenticationService();
$result = $aut->authenticate($adapter); 


var_dump($result);
`

Comment: @jan-m I am using social login(fb/linkedin/gplus) so don't have password. I do all authentication on client side using js sdk. Can it be used in my case ?

Comment: afcourse, you get positive response from facebook (auth ok) then just double check if everything is ok and do the "auth" you must set Identity otherwise zf2 auth isnt complete